# Error getting api vue js objects on my localhost

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm just starting to learn vue js. I can't figure out how to get objects and output each object individually through the Axios API. I found an example and it works, but when I substitute my endpoint it doesn't work

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 

<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8" /> 
<script src= 
 "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"> 
</script> 
<script src= 
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.js"> 
</script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
</head> 

<body> 
<div id="app-vue"> 
    <div class="users"> 
        <div v-if="errored"> 
            
                We're sorry, we're not able to  
                retrieve this information at the  
                moment, please try back later 
             
        </div> 

        <div v-else> 
            <h4 v-if="loading"> 
                Loading... 
            </h4> 
            <div v-for="post in posts" 
                :key="post" class="post"> 
                {{post.title}} 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div> 

<script> 
    new Vue({ 
        el: '#app-vue', 
        data() { 
            return { 
                posts: null, 
                loading: false, 
                errored: false 
            } 
        }, 
        created() { 

            // Creating loader 
            this.loading = true; 
            this.posts = null 

            axios.get( 
    `http://localhost:8083/workers`) 
                .then(response => { 

                    // JSON responses are  
                    // automatically parsed 
                    this.posts = JSON.stringify(response.data);
                }) 

                // Dealing with errors 
                .catch(error => { 
                    console.log(error) 
                    this.errored = true 
                }) 
        } 
    }); 
</script>
```

This is what my browser displays my endpoint on localhost

```
[{"id":1,"name":"name","password":"pass"},{"id":2,"name":null,"password":"pass"},{"id":3,"name":null,"password":"pass"},{"id":4,"name":"","password":"pass"},{"id":5,"name":null,"password":"pass"}]
```

But when I try to pull data, I get an error handling
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwmMH.png)

But if you substitute the test api for educational purposes, then everything displays

```
http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
```

Comment: Screenshot of your own custom error message isn't helpful.  What is the error logged in your console, which is provided by the `catch` block?